# Android Google Fit Integration is erratic and results in sign-in required error

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have a already working code in production version of my app that allows me to integrate Google Fit.

My app uses Google Fit to record user's activity sessions.
Here is the config

`GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context);
            builder.addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API);
            builder.addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API);
            builder.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE));`

Libraries used

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1"`

`min sdk = 19`
`target sdk = 29`

As I migrated to Android-x I started to see this erratic behavior where as when app triggers the Google Fit connect flow, it results in `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` most of the time however at times its  succeeds  as well. here is the error I see

`ConnectionResult`

is reported as

`ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{164aba0: android.os.BinderProxy@69e2129}, message=null}`

How should I debug to what is the real problem is?
NOTE: When app trigger google sign in  dialog, I do follow through by picking my login from the a/c

Thanks